# IndexError: string index out of range, error in function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've done some code in python on jupyter notebook to analyze a list of sequences of genes. When I run, it prints the lengths of `a` and `b`, the two input strings. It then gives me an error.

Below, the function and the error is provided.

```
def hamming_distance(string1, string2): 
    distance = 1
    L = len(string1)
    for i in range(L):
        if string1[i] != string2[i]:
            distance += 1

    return distance
```

---

```
      'len a=', 123, ' lenb b', 122)

  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-c459e7a881a4> in <module>()
      2 b= Sequences.index[1]
      3 print('len a=', len(a), ' lenb b', len(b))
----> 4 hamming_distance(a, b)

<ipython-input-24-c7ce8bb7c40a> in hamming_distance(string1, string2)
      9     for i in range(L):
     10         # Add 1 to the distance if these two characters are not equal
---> 11         if string1[i] != string2[i]:
     12             distance += 1
     13     # Return the final count of differences

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: It looks like you only look at the length of string1. If string2 is shorter than string1 your for loop will look for a character that doesnt exist in string2 because it is beyond the word that was entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `string2` is shorter than your `string1` by at least one character. Let's say you have

```
string1 = "Hollow"
string2 = "Hello"
```

Then, when `i == 5`, you end up looking for

```
string1[5] --> "w"
string2[5] --> IndexError
```

To avoid this happening, you want to either *cap `L` at the length of the shorter string*, like so:

```
L = min(len(string1), len(string2))
```

or come up with a special case for when the lengths don't match (the Hamming Distance assumes by default that the strings are the same length. If you're wanting to compare strings of different length, you might want to look into using [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) instead. [There is a python module for this](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/)).

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your code if string2 is shorter than string1.  If that's the case, you're going to end up trying to compare characters at later positions in string1 that don't exist in string2.

I'm not sure if this is the right way to fix this, but you could define L to be:

```
L = min(len(string1), len(string2))
```

This would compare as many characters as possible until you reach the end of one of the strings.

Your example data would definitely have this problem.  You will compare 122 characters in both strings, but then for that last character, you'll get this error because there is no character in string2 at position 122 (the 123rd character in the string).

Comment: Probable confirmation `'len a=', 123, ' lenb b', 122`